# Fn + F10 writes out the letter "p". How do I study this?

Tags: xubuntu, 22.04, shortcut-keys, function-keys

I've recently discovered that Fn + F10 produces "p", but only in text editors such as Geany or Mousepad. Other function keys, such as Fn + F9 do expected things like lock my screen. I'd post information about my PC and software, but I don't have the slightest idea what could be relevant. Instead, rather than ask for a fix, I'm asking this: Where do I look for relevant information for understanding/debugging this?

`xev` shows the following:

```bash
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x7600001,
    root 0x1a1, subw 0x0, time 23328457, (164,-6), root:(1313,476),
    state 0x0, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x7600001,
    root 0x1a1, subw 0x0, time 23328460, (164,-6), root:(1313,476),
    state 0x40, keycode 33 (keysym 0x70, p), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (70) "p"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (70) "p"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x7600001,
    root 0x1a1, subw 0x0, time 23328603, (164,-6), root:(1313,476),
    state 0x40, keycode 33 (keysym 0x70, p), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (70) "p"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x7600001,
    root 0x1a1, subw 0x0, time 23328609, (164,-6), root:(1313,476),
    state 0x40, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For debugging: Open a terminal and run `xev`. Now press the `Fn+F10` keys. In the output look for `KeyPress` and `KeyRelease` events, e.g. on my laptop `Fn+F10` is the key for toggling Bluetooth. As you can see, `xev` reports this key as `XF86Bluetooth`.

```
KeyPress event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x9800001,
    root 0x7a5, subw 0x0, time 147780896, (74,64), root:(945,511),
    state 0x0, keycode 245 (keysym 0x1008ff94, XF86Bluetooth), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x9800001,
    root 0x7a5, subw 0x0, time 147780896, (74,64), root:(945,511),
    state 0x0, keycode 245 (keysym 0x1008ff94, XF86Bluetooth), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: I've added the relevant output to the question. Don't suppose you've got any insight?

Comment: @J.Mini Unfortunately not really. You can look up the hexadecimal keycode in [keysymdef.h](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/x11proto/tree/keysymdef.h), which is the same as `xev` does anyways. In your case the keycode is `0x0070`, which really corresponds to `p`. Unfortunately I can't help further